# Find the customer with maximum amount in HIVE

Tags: hive

I have a table in HIVE named **my_table** as follows.

```
sub_no -- P_date -- amount
111 -- 27-09-2015 -- 100
112 -- 27-09-2015 -- 200
113 -- 27-09-2015 -- 300
112 -- 27-09-2015 -- 400
116 -- 27-09-2015 -- 500
117 -- 27-09-2015 -- 600
111 -- 27-09-2015 -- 100
112 -- 27-09-2015 -- 200
```

I will have to find the **sub_no** who has the maximum **sum(amount)** using HQL.

Here my required output is **112    -- 27-09-2015 --    800**

Can someone tell me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Hive supports `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, so:

```
select t.sub_no, sum(amount) as total_amount
from my_table t
order by sum(amount) desc
limit 1;
```

Note that Hive does not support `order by total_amount desc`, although most other databases do.